# Parallel foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I have two foreach loops:

**1st**

```
 foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $achievement){
  if(!empty($achievement['rewardItems'])){
    foreach ($achievement['rewardItems'] as $item){
      echo "$item[name] $item[id]<br/>".PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
}
```

**2nd**

```
foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) echo '

                        <li class="span3 clearfix" data-tag=', $item['qualityId'], '>
                                <a
                                        href="//de.wowhead.com/achievement=', $item['id'], '"
                                        class="', $item['qualityId'], '"
                                >
                                        <img
                                                src="http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/', $item['icon'], '.jpg"
                                                alt="', htmlspecialchars($item['name']), '"
                                        >
                                </a>
', $item['name'], '.
                        </li>';
```

They both are running for themselves. But I need them to run parallel, because I need the result from the 1st foreach loop into the result of the second loop.

Comment: What results do you need in the second foreach? Can you make a simple example of what you have/get now and what you try to get.

Comment: In the first loop i get the $item[name] out of the ['rewardItems'] array. I need this in the <li></li> of the second array. Now i have the results separated, i need them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you don't need parallel processing. You just need a second level loop. Try this code if it helps.

```
    foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) {
        echo '<li class="span3 clearfix" data-tag=', $item['qualityId'], '>';

        if(!empty($item['rewardItems'])){
            foreach ($item['rewardItems'] as $item1){
              echo "$item1[name] $item1[id]<br/>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        echo '                           <a
                                            href="//de.wowhead.com/achievement=', $item['id'], '"
                                            class="', $item['qualityId'], '"
                                    >
                                            <img
                                                    src="http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/', $item['icon'], '.jpg"
                                                    alt="', htmlspecialchars($item['name']), '"
                                            >
                                    </a>
    ', $item['name'], '.
                            </li>';
                        }
```

Please provide your current output and desired output. That will make us more clear about what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah thank you! That´s what i´ve searched!